# How to get HTML code after logging in?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am quite new to Selenium, it would be great if you guys can point me to the right direction.

I'm trying to access the HTML code of a website AFTER the login sequence.
I've used Selenium to direct the browser to initiate the login sequence, the part of the HTML I need will show up after I login. But when I tried to call the HTML code after the login sequence with page_source, it just gave me the HTML code for the site before logging in.

```
def test_script(ticker):
    base_url = "http://amigobulls.com/stocks/%s/income-statement/quarterly" %ticker
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    verificationErrors = []
    accept_next_alert = True    
    driver.get(base_url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//header[@id='header_cont']/nav/div[4]/div/span[3]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_email").send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_pswd").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_pswd").send_keys(pwd)
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn").click()

    amigo_script = driver.page_source
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really pass authorization and linked to target page? Can you check it with `driver.title`?

Comment: May be you shall introduce a wait after clicking the login button, refer to this link for documentation http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: The title is the same regardless if I'm signed in or not. I think I am in because my firefox window is in...Is that a right concept?